# The options "choices", "multiple" do not exist

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

I am editing a Sonata-generated admin class. It deals with filtering of videos based on planned and completed distributions. The class already contains the following:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('producedTill', 'doctrine_orm_date', [], 'sonata_type_datetime_picker',
            $this->getDatePickerDefinitions(2, true, 3))
        ->add('plannedDistributions', null, [], null,
            $this->getEntityDefinitions('AppBundle:DistributionChannel', 1, true, 4))
}
```

... which gives me a nice UI that includes a dropdown for the "planned distributions" field in my app.

Now I want to add another dropdown for completed distributions. I add the following:

```
        ->add('distributions', null, [], null,
            $this->getEntityDefinitions('AppBundle:DistributionChannel', 1, true, 4))
```

... but on reloading the list view, I get this message:

> The options "choices", "multiple" do not exist. Defined options are:
>   "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize",
>   "block_name", "by_reference", "cascade_validation", "compound",
>   "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection",
>   "csrf_provider", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data",
>   "data_class", "description", "disabled", "empty_data",
>   "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message",
>   "horizontal_input_wrapper_class", "horizontal_label_class",
>   "horizontal_label_offset_class", "inherit_data", "intention",
>   "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label",
>   "label_attr", "label_format", "label_render", "mapped", "max_length",
>   "method", "pattern", "post_max_size_message", "property_path",
>   "read_only", "required", "sonata_admin", "sonata_field_description",
>   "sonata_help", "translation_domain", "trim",
>   "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups", "virtual".

I don't believe I tried to define any "choices" or "multiple" options within my `configureDatagridFilters` method. What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Well that was easy -- the `getEntityDefinitions()` method contains references to those fields.

```
public function getEntityDefinitions($entityName, $innerSort = null, $extended = false, $sort = 1)
{
    return array(
        'choices' => $this->entityManager->getRepository($entityName)->getSortedElements($this->getLocale()),
        'multiple' => true,
        'attr' => array(
            'data-extended' => $extended,
            'data-sort' => $sort,
            'data-inner-sort' => $innerSort
        )
    );
}
```